# How to find which postgresql text fields do contain most occurances of a specific string?

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for a SQL query that would list me the fields that do contain a specific string more times.

While it very easy to search for a string, I do want to sort the results based on number of occurences.

```
select count(*) from bodycontent WHERE body LIKE '%tag%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    body,
    (select count(*) from regexp_matches(body, 'tag', 'gi')) ocurr
from bodycontent
order by ocurr desc
```

The `i` flag will make a case insensitive match.

Comment: If using this approach, be careful to ensure you have escaped the right characters to avoid the regex matching too broadly, as there are many more "special" characters in a full regex than a `LIKE` pattern.

Comment: Oh, and `tag` in the example should be `'tag'` - it's a string, not a column/variable reference.

Answer (score 1):

Select the length of the value minus the length of the value after the searched-for string has been replaced with zero-length string, divided by the length of the searched-for string.

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20091020172452.GA10593@tux

Answer (score 0):

I found this on a Chinese website, but at least the code was readable:

```
create or replace function regexp_count(str text,search text) returns int as $$
declare
  str_len int;
  search_len int;
  i int;
begin
  str_len := length(str);
  search_len := length(search);
  i := 0;
  for x in 1..str_len-search_len+1 loop
    if substr(str, x, search_len) = search then
      i := i+1;
    end if;
  end loop;
  return i;
end;
$$ language plpgsql strict;


 select * from regexp_count('i am digoal test test', 'test');
```

Maybe someone else has a shorter solution... or even a faster one.